# React useState hook - when to use previous state when updating state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the code below, the form is not updated correctly unless I pass in previous state to the state setting call ('setForm').

To see it in action, run the code as-is, and the console will print 'true', indicating it worked. That's using 'validate1' function. If you replace that with 'validate2' (which doesn't use previous state), it fails to print 'true'.

It seems like in validate2, the second setForm call overwrites the form.long state of the first setForm call, due to the async nature of these calls. But why does validate1 work? Why does using previous state cause it to work? Any documentation on this behavior would be really helpful.

(I can make validate2 work by having one setForm that sets both fields, but the code below is contrived to show a difference in the two ways setForm can be called, with and without previous state.)

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-shamir-jc79r)

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;


function LoginForm() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
    long: null
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(form.long);
  }, [form.long]);

  const validate1 = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setForm((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      long: form.password.length >=3 ? true : false
    }));
    setForm((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      username: "*****"
    }));
  };

  const validate2 = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setForm({
      ...form,
      long: form.password.length >=3 ? true : false
    });
    setForm({
      ...form,
      username: "*****"
    });
  };

  const updateField = (e) => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={validate1}>
      <label>
        Username:
        <input value={form.username} name="username" onChange={updateField} />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Password:
        <input
          value={form.password}
          name="password"
          type="password"
          onChange={updateField}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}


// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <LoginForm/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Using a hook var in a function would add in a dependency. Therefore React has this neat way of using previous state to set new state without adding the old state as a dependency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), they mention the following,

> If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the
> updater function form, instead:

```
this.setState((state) => {
  return {quantity: state.quantity + 1};
});
```

That's the reason validate1 works, because the second call to setForm depends on the previous setForm call state, and the state will be up to date if the updater function form is used.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does validate1 work though? Why does using previous state cause it to work?

```
setForm({
  ...form,
  long: form.password.length >=3 ? true : false
});
setForm({
  ...form,
  username: "*****"
});
```

The value of `form` in the second `setForm` is still the old value until the next re-render. It doesn't reflect the updated `form` from the previous `setForm`.

React `setState` and `useState` does not make changes directly to the state object.

`setState` and `useState` create queues for React core to update the state object of a React component.

So the process to update React state is asynchronous for performance reasons. That’s why changes don’t feel immediate.

https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately

Comment: I understand why validate2 (the code you pasted) fails. What I don't get is why validate1 works, the code that uses previous state.

Comment: where did you see the documentation for `prevState` in `setForm`?

Comment: Here are a couple of sources: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html and https://daveceddia.com/usestate-hook-examples/. Just search for 'previous state'.

Comment: @Ravi the reason that `validate1` works with `prevState` is because you have the **guarantee** that will reflect the last state when you already have dispatched the other changes from the input fields.

Comment: @VictorBarros so using prevState somehow serializes multiple state updates?

Comment: @Ravi not exactly, it guarantee that the function your function `setForm` will get the last mutable object at the moment of the update, after all other state changes that are still promised. I created this same example for you to understand, the wrong function simulates the effect `onChange` in the input field and calling the submit in sequence. https://codesandbox.io/s/handle-with-state-concurrence-3cs9p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @VictorBarros thank you for the CodeSandbox. For the correct method, you say "state used by `setForm` in my last call has the value of the previous call that as dispatched first". Do you know if there's documentation on this behavior? From your example and mine, I can see that it's true, but I would like to know if it's well documented. Why would anyone *not* use previous state, especially if there are multiple calls to set state?

Comment: @Ravi unfortunately I din't find any mention to this in the documentation. I got this insights after looking into the source code and experimentation. :-)

Comment: @VictorBarros appreciate that. If no one else comes up with a link to documentation, I'll accept yours if you create an answer for it.